# Why is 'dotnet new webapi' command not producing the controllers folder?

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, dotnet-cli, .net-8.0

Upon using `dotnet new webapi -n API` it produces the API folder with the `properties`, `obj` and `bin` subfolders as in the screenshot below, but it doesn't have a `Controllers` folder. Can anyone guide me on this? The project is using .NET 8.0

[image: Image1]

Comment: What tutorial ? It could really help if we knew

Comment: Is it creating a (somewhat new) "minimal API"?  The tutorial could be for an older version of the tools.

Comment: The course is 'ASP NET CORE' by Neil Cummings and yes it is from like 2020 or 2021.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems to be a recent .NET 8 change resulting in the [Minimal APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/minimal-apis?view=aspnetcore-8.0) used by default.

From the docs for [dotnet new templates: webapi](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-new-sdk-templates#webapi) (with fixed typo - [PR @github](https://github.com/dotnet/docs/pull/38854)):

> - `-minimal`|`--use-minimal-apis`
>   Create a project that uses the ASP.NET Core minimal API. Default is false, but this option is overridden by `--controllers`. Since the default for `--controllers` is `false`, **entering `dotnet new webapi` without specifying either option creates a minimal API project**.

> - `-controllers`|`--use-controllers`
>   Whether to use controllers instead of minimal APIs. If both this option and `-minimal` are specified, this option overrides the value specified by `-minimal`. Default is `false`. **Available since .NET 8 SDK**.

So add `-controllers`/`--use-controllers` option to the command to get controllers:

```
dotnet new webapi -n API --use-controllers
```

Or

```
dotnet new webapi -n API -controllers
```

Comment: @haroonkhan was glad to help! If answer works for you  - feel free to mark it as accepted one (checkmark to the left)

Answer (score 2):

That command creates a [Minimal API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/minimal-apis?view=aspnetcore-8.0) by default as shown [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-new-sdk-templates#webapi).
A minimal web API does not have controllers.

Since the default for -controllers is false, entering `dotnet new webapi` without specifying the option creates a minimal API project.

To create a web API with controllers run the following command instead:

`dotnet new webapi -controllers -n API`

OR

`dotnet new webapi --use-controllers -n API`

Comment: Note that there is typo in the docs - `--controllers` will not actually work (see my answer)

Comment: @GuruStron thank you for the correction, glad there is a PR that already addresses this